# how to show both PasswordToggle icon and background drawable in TextInputLayout?

Tags: android, android-textinputlayout

I want to set a background drawable for my TextInputLayout , this is my code :

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/input_layout_repass"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="37dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            app:hintEnabled="false"
            android:layoutDirection="rtl"
            app:passwordToggleEnabled="true">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/repass"
                style="@style/edittexts"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/hint_repass"
                android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_https_grey600_18dp"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:nextFocusDown="@+id/email" />

        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

the problem is,  the icon is not appearing, the reason is that of `passwordToggleEnabled` when I remove it, it shows the drawable

how to show both `PasswordToggle Drawable` and `background drawable`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_launcher_round"
```

instead of

```
android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_launcher_round"
```

Try this

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/input_layout_repass"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layoutDirection="rtl"
    app:hintEnabled="false"
    app:passwordToggleEnabled="true">


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/repass"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_launcher_round"
        android:hint="nilu"
        android:imeOptions="actionNext"
        android:inputType="textPassword" />


</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

**NOTE :** `android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_launcher_round"` is working because of `android:layoutDirection="rtl"`

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Comment: can you tell the reason why the drawable show when we put drawableStart with right despite the fact that both are opposite to each other ?
android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_launcher_round"
        android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_launcher_round"

Comment: @Umair you can check in your device its woking

Comment: yes i know it's working I am just asking the reason :) It seems really wired

Comment: @Umair reason i don't know may be it because of `app:passwordToggleEnabled`

Comment: @Umair got it **`drawableStart`** working because of `android:layoutDirection="rtl"`

Comment: I don't think that's the case because if you reverse the layoutDirection you it still works. And if you remove this attribute completely it still works:)

Comment: and by the way it also works only if you put android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_launcher_round" this line and remove the other. :)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
     <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/rl_main"
        android:padding="@dimen/margin_30dp"
        android:background="@color/white_color">

       <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_email"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/margin_25dp"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/margin_25dp"
        android:src="@drawable/message"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_15dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
/>
        <!--Email-->
        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/til_email_login_activity"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:hint="@string/email"
            android:textColorHint="@color/gray">

            <com.xxx.app.customeview.CustomFontEditText
                android:id="@+id/et_email_login_activity"
                style="@style/edit_text_style"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                android:text="" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
       </RelativeLayout>
```

for password tongle off use app:passwordToggleEnabled="false"

Answer (score 0):

You have to add this line only

```
android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_action_rupee"
```

Use this code It will working for me.

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/input_layout_repass"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="37dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            app:hintEnabled="false"
            app:passwordToggleEnabled="true">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/repass"
                style="@style/edittexts"
                android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_action_rupee"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/hint_repass"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:nextFocusDown="@+id/email"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_action_rupee" />

        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```